# Jointly Write Large Answer

Tags: discussion

The question [Background removal with hair](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264270/background-removal-with-hair?noredirect=1#comment658770_264270), in my opinion, is unanswerable.  Most image processing questions seem to result in finicky, specialized code.  Moreover, image processing questions seem to be less likely to be flagged as duplicates since it's harder to claim a particular task is effectively accomplished in the same way as another one is (not complaining, simply observing).  These issues are related.

If I had infinite time, I would try to implement the algorithm described [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10489-021-03099-3) or something similar.  Would users on this site be interested in splitting up such a task?

- Perhaps someone does a UI, someone does "preprocessing" and "biometry", someone does "Body hull", someone does "Body map", etc. as described in the paper?
- I or someone else could define functions with specified input/output types to be written to help organize

Obviously sending code between multiple people, testing and using other people's functions etc. is harder than just hacking together your own code, but it may be feasible.

---

I'm just spitballing about how to use the talent on this site better.  P.S. do people on this site work together on larger projects ever, beyond sporadically riffing off others' programs?

Comment: (+1) from me. I'd be glad to try and help, though not sure if I could be useful in any way; perhaps you'd need to attract the really powerful people of the site. But it sounds like lots of fun and -in my opinion and to the extend of my knowledge- would utilize the site in a unique way. Nice suggestion on general grounds! P.S: there are always practical issues that would need to be resolved, but let's not jump ahead

Comment: I don't think this site is for questions that are unanswerable without investing significant resources. Sounds like a candidate for closing with the standard close reason **The question is out of scope for this site. The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support or the services of a professional consultant.** (need 3k+ rep to close)